# Flipping the header for odd and even pages for article

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to print the header for odd and even pages differently. For the odd page, it will be at left like the following
[image]

And for the right it will be at right. I do not want to use `twopage` or `book` since they have mergin problem. I want same amount of mergin in both pages. How to do it?
My try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{feynds}
\author{ts342139 }
\date{October 2023}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\tikzfeynmanset{plain/.style=}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead{LE}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark\hfill}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\hfill\thepage\hfill}
\section{The DY}
\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `twoside` and then adapt the margins (e.g. with geometry).

Comment: no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Your setting is pretty close to the right solution. What you need is to pass `twoside` option to package `fancyhr` option. And define the `fancyhead[LO,RE]` and `\fancyfoot[C]` according your requirements. `\hfill` was not needed, because the location have been confirmed in the option. `[LO,RE]` is odd page left side, even page right side. `[C]` is in the center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{feynds}
\author{ts342139 }
\date{October 2023}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\tikzfeynmanset{plain/.style=}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[twoside]{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{The DY}
\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my case it is not working. After that I have copied this code but still giging error ```Package fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is useless on input line 18```

Comment: @TanmoyPati that presumably means you have not used the `twoside` option (usually best to give it on `\documentclass`)

Comment: @TanmoyPati No, give it for the package `fancyhdr`, otherwise, the margin will switch for odd and even page. Make sure your package are updated. These code didn't show error on my end.